# sci-kit (sklearn) PCA decomposition transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

To manually perform a transformation, I have to matrix multiply the original data (de-meaned) by `PCA().fit(data).components_.T` (the transpose of the components) to get the results to match `PCA().fit_transform(data)`.

Does anyone know if this is intentional, and if so why? Looking at the comments in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py#L106) there is a note that it should be `X_new = X*V`, where V is the components, but I find that it is `X_new = XV^T`.

Comment: Can you motivate your first sentence about PCA().fit(data).components_.T?

Comment: @AlessandroSolbiati Not sure I understand what you mean by motivate. I am moving a simple PCA finance analysis from MATLAB to python and was testing the behaviour of the sklearn PCA() function and realized to get matching results between the two approaches I need to take the transpose of the matrix.